# Script for Storing Record Name & DNS History

Tags: batch-file, powershell, dns

I'm trying to create a simple script that will store all my daily Record Name - DNS History. 
Initially i came up with this script here.

```
@echo off
ipconfig /displaydns > temp.txt
find "Record Name" temp.txt > WebsitesVisited.txt
del temp.txt
```

The problem is that every time i run the bat file, it overrides the previous record name history, so what i want is to create a loop that will generate a different txt file each time i run this script (etc WebsitesVisited1.txt, WebsitesVisited2.txt... WebsitesVisited999.txt).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    set "baseName=WebsitesVisited"

    set "count=0"
    for /f "delims=%baseName%." %%a in (
        'dir /b /o-d "%baseName%*.txt" 2^>nul'
    ) do ( set /a "count=%%a+1" & goto saveData )

:saveData
    ipconfig /displaydns | find "Record Name" > "%baseName%%count%.txt"
```

Search the last matching file, retrieve the number part, increment and save to the new file

Comment: Thanks mate! It did exactly as i wanted! If i may ask, is it possible for that report to be send directly to my email? Etc Generate the file as we just did and send the contents via email?